# For loop with two parameters in and multiple calculations out

Tags: plsql, foreach, parameters

Okay, there must be a better way...  Given constants:

```
create or replace PACKAGE time_conversion_cons AS 
  c_day_to_hr    CONSTANT NUMBER := 24; 
  c_day_to_min   CONSTANT NUMBER := 1440; 
  c_day_to_sec   CONSTANT NUMBER := 86400;
  c_hr_to_day    CONSTANT NUMBER := .0417; 
  c_hr_to_min    CONSTANT NUMBER := 60; 
  c_hr_to_sec    CONSTANT NUMBER := 3600;
  c_min_to_day   CONSTANT NUMBER := .000694; 
  c_min_to_hr    CONSTANT NUMBER := .0167; 
  c_min_to_sec   CONSTANT NUMBER := 60;
  c_sec_to_day   CONSTANT NUMBER := .0001157; 
  c_sec_to_hr    CONSTANT NUMBER := .000478; 
  c_sec_to_min   CONSTANT NUMBER := .167;
END time_conversion_cons; -- this package spec compiles and runs fine.
```

For the input parameters (n, units), where units are (days, hrs, min's, seconds),
convert to the other three and display results.

The following anonymous block compiles, runs and solves the problem.  Is there a way to avoid typing all of the BEGIN...END four times, once for each pair of parameters?

```
DECLARE 
  v_n1 NUMBER := 2.5;
  v_u1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'days';
  v_n2 NUMBER := 1.8;
  v_u2 VARCHAR2(10) := 'hours';
  v_n3 NUMBER := 13;
  v_u3 VARCHAR2(10) := 'minutes';
  v_n4 NUMBER := 720;
  v_u4 VARCHAR2(10) := 'seconds';
BEGIN
  pri(v_n1||' '||v_u1||' is '||
  time_conversion_cons.c_day_to_hr * v_n1||' hours or '||
  time_conversion_cons.c_day_to_min * v_n1||' minutes or '||
  time_conversion_cons.c_day_to_sec * v_n1||' seconds.');
END;
```

Comment: [mcve], please! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL>
SQL> create or replace PACKAGE time_conversion_cons AS
  2    type  dim1 is table of number index by varchar2(10);
  3    type  dim2 is table of dim1   index by varchar2(10);
  4    l_matrix dim2;
  5
  6    l_tags sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('day','hr','min','sec');
  7  end;
  8  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace PACKAGE body time_conversion_cons AS
  2  begin
  3    l_matrix('day')('hr'):= 24;
  4    l_matrix('day')('min'):= 1440;
  5    l_matrix('day')('sec'):= 86400;
  6    l_matrix('hr')('day'):= .0417;
  7    l_matrix('hr')('min'):= 60;
  8    l_matrix('hr')('sec'):= 3600;
  9    l_matrix('min')('day'):= .000694;
 10    l_matrix('min')('hr'):= .0167;
 11    l_matrix('min')('sec'):= 60;
 12    l_matrix('sec')('day'):= .0001157;
 13    l_matrix('sec')('hr'):= .000478;
 14    l_matrix('sec')('min'):= .167;
 15  END;
 16  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_n1 NUMBER := 2.5;
  3    v_u1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'day';
  4  BEGIN
  5    for i in 1 .. time_conversion_cons.l_tags.count loop
  6      if time_conversion_cons.l_tags(i) != v_u1 then
  7         dbms_output.put_line(v_u1||' to '||time_conversion_cons.l_tags(i));
  8         dbms_output.put_line(v_n1*time_conversion_cons.l_matrix(v_u1)(time_conversion_cons.l_tags(i)));
  9      end if;
 10    end loop;
 11  END;
 12  /
day to hr
60
day to min
3600
day to sec
216000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Connor McDonald.  I appreciate the help!